# CSRF TEST and mismatched value trouble

Tags: php, post, cookies, csrf, mismatch

```
<!doctype html> 

<meta charset="utf-8"> 


<title> T CSRF_TEST.php </title>

<style> html * { font-size:1.75rem; font-family:monospace; } </style>

<?php
// Generate a CSRF token and store it in a cookie
$csrfToken = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
setcookie("csrfToken", $csrfToken, time() + 3600);


?>


<form action="CSRF_TEST.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['csrfToken']; ?>">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="refreshPage()">

</form>

<?php
echo "<br>";

$TOKEN = $_POST["csrfToken"];
echo "<br>TOKEN= " . $TOKEN;

$TOKEN2 = $_COOKIE['csrfToken'];
echo "<br>TOKEN2= " . $TOKEN2;

// On the server side, verify the CSRF token
if ($_POST['csrfToken'] !== $_COOKIE['csrfToken']) {
  // CSRF token mismatch
  // Reject the request
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Reject the request";
}
else
{
  echo "APPROVED REQUEST";
}

?>

<script>
function refreshPage() {
  window.location.replace("CSRF_TEST.php");
}
</script>
```

I am running this program and obtain two different value in the conditional ($_POST['csrfToken'] !== $_COOKIE['csrfToken']) test . As I know the generative CSRF token is stored in cookie then the same is POST to php and i cannot realize why the values are different.

Comment: Every time you reload the page, after a submit, a new cookie value is created and set.

Comment: KIKO i asked the question because i am trying to test if my small program is a bit secure against CSRF attack. it is more or less didactic. in your comment you suggest that is impossibile a match between $_POST['csrfToken']  and $_COOKIE['csrfToken'] ,  is it right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I think what you want is to only create a new cookie value when it isn't set. So: `if (!isset($_COOKIE['csrfToken'])) { .... create cookie .... }`. That way it can be the same value as `$_POST['csrfToken']` because you don't overwrite it every time.

Comment: KIKO thanks for the suggestion, you mean


if (!isset($_COOKIE['csrfToken'])) { $csrfToken = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
setcookie("csrfToken", $csrfToken, time() + 3600); }

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Create and set the cookie once for new visitors to your page.

Comment: I think you should send the cookie **before** any output.

Comment: Markus Zeller, the cookie expires after 3600 sec (1 hour) so i have difficult to reinstate the cookie hence the programm has a fault because cookie for CSRF_TEST.php survives only 3600 secs.